# i want to cast the component in order to use it

Tags: angular

i use the child routing. I get the parent component in the active route.But i don't know how to cast it in order to use it and call the methods.

```
constructor( public router : Router, public route : ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() { 
    let comp =  (this.route.parent.component as Type<RegisterComponent>); 
    console.log(comp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two different ways:

```
let comp = <RegisterComponent> this.route.parent.component;
```

Or

```
let comp = this.route.parent.component as RegisterComponent;
```

Comment: thaniks for you answer. when i do this, the editor show an error : type string | Type<any> cannot convert to type RegisterComponent. Type 'Type<any>' is not comparable to typr RegisterComponent. Why ???